# gdm - how to rotate screen with xrandr

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, xrandr, gdm, i3-wm

I have a default install of ubuntu 18.04, plus i3 installed.  i3 probably not relevant, but providing it for context as having the screen rotated in the window manager is 90% of what i need.

Looking at the `man gdm3`, i see it will load `/etc/gdm3/Init/Default` (I have no `display` file).  I tried adding the correct command (use `arandr` to generate the necessary `xrandr` command string).

- adding the `xrandr` command to the end of `/etc/gdm3/Init/Default` --> nothing changes, `gdm3` loads find BUT without the rotation changed, and I can log in.
- adding it to `/etc/gdm3/PreSession/Default` --> After entering my password on gdm, something crashes and i'm bounced back to the gdm logon screen.

if i run this same xrandr line from *after* i log into an `i3` session, it works as expected.

- for reference, `arandr` gave me:

  xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --off --output HDMI-0 --off --output DP-5 --off --output DP-4 --mode 3840x2160 --pos 6000x1680 --rotate normal --output DP-3 --off --output DP-2 --mode 3840x2160 --pos 2160x1680 --rotate normal --output DP-1 --off --output DP-0 --mode 3840x2160 --pos 0x0 --rotate left
- one vertical 4k monitor to the left of two horizontal 4k's.

Ideally, how do I get my monitors rotated "from the get go" (eg, GDM displays rotated correctly).  Alternatively, where can i run that `xrandr` to get the `i3` session correctly rotated?

I tried google, `man` for both, and the i3 user guide, but couldn't find an answer to this.